# Meaning of "at least a quarter" in the quoted sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

Consider the sentence,

> Any small and medium startup validates and rethinks the focus area at
>   least a quarter which might change the approach towards their
>   offerings

What does the "at least a quarter" mean here? Is it same as "at least a quarter of every year"?

Is it grammatically right?

Comment: As quoted it means bupkis. It might be intended to mean "rethinks the focus area every quarter" or some such, but there's no way to tell.  Are you sure you quoted it correctly, with all the words and punctuation?

Comment: It should probably be "at least once a quarter".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "quarter" in a business context means a three-month period. Businesses often refer to quarterly earnings, quarterly sales, etc.

It is not grammatical as it stands. It must be missing a word--"at least *once* a quarter," "*twice* a quarter," etc., or "at least every quarter" or "every other quarter," or some such.

It almost certainly does not mean "at least a quarter of every year." That would mean that the business spends a three-month period every year refocusing, and letting the rest of the year go by on the basis of that three-month effort. Businesses do not generally operate that way. Typically, they review their practices (or at least they should) on a continual basis--again, they look at earnings every quarter, for example. And, if it does mean "at least a quarter of every year," it still isn't grammatical. In that unlikely case, this should read "*for* at least a quarter."